# оздал TEdit динамически, не могу в него ничего писать в программе, даже выделить не могу

Tags: c++, c++builder, text, radstudio, компоненты

Создал TEdit динамически, не могу в него ничего писать в программе, даже выделить не могу

```
ned1 = new TEdit(TabControl4);
ned1->Parent =  TabControl4;
ned1->Width = 150;
ned1->Position->X= 200;
ned1->Position->Y= 0;
ned1->CanFocus = true;
ned1->ReadOnly= false;
```

если просто добавить на форме TEdit то в него сразу можно записи делать.
Подскажите что сделать? может обработчик какой то нужен? Или может потому что в TabControl создал? хотя на другом TabControl работает статический edit

язык с++, программа radstudio c++builder под андроид

Comment: Мне кажется, что сначала его нужно сделать видимым, а визуальные операции с невидимкой делать безполезно. После Parent или Width вписать `ned1->Visible = true;`

Comment: он изначально видим